# Copy folder to another location by excluding all sub folders that have a specific name

Tags: bash, rsync

I need to backup my `devprojects` folder, but it contains a subfolder for every project, and most of the projects have a `node_modules` folder that has many many files. This causes my backups to be extremely slow.

Any ideas on how to copy my data without the `node_modules` folders? I do not really need that at all.

This is the script that I am using now. However, it does not work as expected. I assume just one `node_modules` is excluded. Others still get copied:

```
rsync -av --progress -exclude="node_modules" source destination
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `-` before `-exclude`. The correct command is:

```
rsync -av --progress --exclude="node_modules" source destination
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks ! Works now